# Symfony 1.4, Doctrine 1.2 : After editing an object, other related objects are deleted ?

Tags: mysql, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

in my app, a monitor has many benchmarks (1 to many)
in the monitor editing interface, when i save the modifications every benchmark having monitor_id the one that i edited is DELETED !

```
Monitor:
  tableName: monitor
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
  columns:
    id : {type: integer(4), primary: true, autoincrement: true}
    label: {type: string(45)}
    url: {type: string(80)}
    frequency: {type: integer}
    timeout: {type: integer}
    method: {type: enum, values: [GET, POST, HEAD, PUT, DELETE]}
    parameters: {type: string(255)}
    active : { type: boolean, notnull: true, default: 1 }
  relations:
    GroupsByAlert:
      class: sfGuardGroup
      local: monitor_id
      foreign: sf_guard_group_id
      refClass: Alert
      foreignAlias: Groups
    Accidents:
      class: Accident
      local: id
      foreign: monitor_id

Benchmark:
  #detect_relations: true
  tableName: benchmark
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
  columns:
    #id: {type: integer(4), primary: true,autoincrement: true}
    monitor_id: { type: integer(4)}
    server_id: { type: integer(4)}
    connexionTime: {type: string(45)}
    executionTime: {type: string(45)}
    responseTime: {type: string(45)}
    responseCode: {type: string(45)}
    responseMessage: {type: string(45)}
    responseBody: {type: blob}
  relations:
    Monitor:
      class: Monitor
      local: monitor_id
      foreign: id
    Server:
      class: Server
      local: server_id
      foreign: id
```

Any idea?

Comment: Of course this shouldn't happen. Can you show your code where you retrieve, edit and save your `Benchmark`?

Comment: it when i edit a monitor ! monnitor is a module generated with admin Generator, so the edit is automatically performed! am here for further infos !

Comment: actually the monitor edit has nothing to do with the benchmark!, the benchmarks uses the monitor's url only in a task (wich has nothing to do with the monitor edit)

Comment: all what the edit monitor should do is modify and do nothing else. BUT it still delete the benchmarks that have ` "monito_id" = this monitor`

Comment: please, does anybody have any idea of what would be the problem ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer guys,
actually it's a field that i ommited in the generator.yml and forgot to unset, hense Doctrine didn't know what to do and in stead it started by deleting every related object and recreating an other !